# How to send full strings from python to telegram which contain the substring"#"

Tags: python, url, python-requests, tags, telegram

I have this function:

```
import requests
def sendTelegram(message):
        token = "********************"
        chat_id = "**********"
        url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={message}"
        requests.get(url).json()
```

Which prints a message to my telegram chat via bot. But I have a problem, the strings that I want to print to my chat are not full sometimes. When the substring "#" is met within the string that needs to be printed, the print of the string closes there.

Example:

```
sendTelegram('https://www.coolwebsite/page1#page2') -> prints 'https://www.coolwebsite/page1'
```

Any solve to this situation, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telegram supports both passing arguments throught [query string and JSON body](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#making-requests), but using the query string version exposes you to special characters, like `#?=` for example

So to avoid any url escaping requirement, use the POST version

```
def sendTelegram(message):
    token = "********************"
    chat_id = "**********"
    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage"
    content = {"chat_id": chat_id, "text", message}
    requests.post(url, json=content)
```